# Camel 2.20.2: Call get() with Simple Expression Language from SoapMessage throw a ParameterBindingException

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

After I update from camel 2.17.03 to 2.20.2, I get an exception if I try to call the get method from StringMapImpl/SoapMessage

For example, this snippet works fine under 2.17.03:

```
<setBody>
  <simple>
    ${header.CamelCxfMessage.get("http.base.path")}
  </simple>
</setBody>
```

But under 2.20.2 I get the following exception:

> Unexpected exception: Failed to invoke method: get("http.base.path")
> on null due to:
> org.apache.camel.component.bean.ParameterBindingException: Error
> during parameter binding on method: public java.lang.Object
> org.apache.cxf.message.StringMapImpl.get(java.lang.Class) at parameter
> #0 with type: class java.lang.Class with value type: class java.lang.String and value: http.base.path
>
> org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed
> to invoke method: get("http.base.path") on null due to:
> org.apache.camel.component.bean.ParameterBindingException: Error
> during parameter binding on method: public java.lang.Object
> org.apache.cxf.message.StringMapImpl.get(java.lang.Class) at parameter
> #0 with type: class java.lang.Class with value type: class java.lang.String and value: http.base.path

Is this a Bug or changed something in the simple language syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The Apache CXF class `StringMapImpl` [1] has the `get` method using a `Class` type, and your Camel route you pass in a string value. So this was wrong from the very beginning.

[1] - https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/message/StringMapImpl.java

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But under 2.17.03 its works and its was understandable for me because `StringMapImpl` extends `HashMap<String, Object>`. So I think the framework invoke the get method from `HashMap<String,Object>`. Can you give me example for the right using?